# Sample covariance of t distribution and degree of freedom

Tags: covariance-matrix, degrees-of-freedom, t-distribution, correlation-matrix, sampling-distribution

If $X$ is a P by N size matrix, $X_{ij} \sim N(0,\sigma_i^2)$ if I standardize this X matrix with sample mean and sample variance (assuming I don't have access to the population mean and variance) I have a matrix Y of P by N size with $Y_{ij}=\frac{X_{ij}-\bar X_i}{\bar\sigma_i}$ and $Y_{ij}$ is follows t-distribution with $ N-1$ degrees of freedom. Now if I estimate the sample covariance matrix of this $Y$ matrix this will be the same as that of the sample correlation of matrix $X$. My question is when I look at the degrees of freedom lost shouldn't that be two, i.e. the sample covariance of $Y$ should be resulting in lose of a degree of freedom and one lost while standardizing the original $X_{ij}$. Am I right? and how can I show this?

Comment: You don't lose any df in standardizing, because it's superfluous.  It's unclear, though, what you might mean by df, because it has at least two possible and different senses: the parameter for the t distributions or for purposes of formal testing of covariances or correlations.  Which do you mean?

Comment: I am trying to show that a sample correlation matrix of a gaussian matrix with diagonal covariance structure is a wishart matrix with N-2 degrees of freedom.